# What does TFS mean by Keeping a nonexistent file or Automerging with it?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, visual-studio-2003, automerge

When trying to merge a newer version of a project with an older one, I get, "The item has been deleted in the target branch" and it gives me three options:

```
Restore File And AutoMerge
Keep Target Branch Version
Take Source Branch Version
```

...as can be seen here:

[image]

If the file does not exist in the Target area, how could I "Keep Target Branch Version" - does it mean by that, "don't copy over the missing file"?

And how could I "Restore File And AutoMerge" - restoring it is adding it, sure, but AutoMerging? How do you automerge a single file?

What is the safe course of action when presented with these three confusing options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the file does not exist in the Target area, how could I "Keep
>   Target Branch Version" - does it mean by that, "don't copy over the
>   missing file"?

Yes **Keep Target Branch Version** Keep what exists, target remains deleted

> And how could I "Restore File And AutoMerge" - restoring it is adding
>   it, sure, but AutoMerging? How do you automerge a single file?

**Restore File And AutoMerge**
Take the previous version and merge your changes. You will end up with the old target version merged the source file taking precedence

**Take Source Branch Version**
ignore the target and just take the source version

If you need your new file for your app to run then **Take Source Branch Version**

Comment: But there's only one file - the source file. Merging makes no sense; you can't merge with yourself. IOW, the file does not exist in the Target Branch. It's like the 49ers saying to the Vikings, "we'll give our Michael Crabtree to replace your Michael Crabtree, when they don't have a Michael Crabtree.

Comment: You would have two files. The restored target file and the potentially altered file that you are merging in.

Comment: this really makes no sense. source control shouldn't have to worry about whether something has been deleted in the past, it should be comparing the current version to the previous version.  if the previous was deleted, then it's obvious what the intention is